# Where was Beckett heading after leaving with the Coaxium?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

Close to the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, Tobias Beckett first betrayed Han, then Dryden Vos, and attempted to keep the two cases of the refined Coaxium for himself. He took Chewbacca as a prisoner and abandoned Vos' ship leaving him, Han, and Qi'ra fight each other. Beckett and Chewie left on foot and ended up only on a sandy shore of Savareen.

[image]

But where was Beckett planning to go? He couldn't have been sure it was Vos, who got killed in the skirmish, and he most likely would have been after him soon. Still, there was nothing, no ship nor vessel of any kind, at least in sight, where he was heading to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were some small ships in a nearby community that had the capability of reaching orbit. Presumably Beckett was going to barter/buy/steal/hijack one of them.

> THE SUN WAS SINKING below the Emerald Sea, solar flares bursting above, when Han finally caught up with them. From his vantage point in the dunes, he had a clear view looking down on Beckett and Chewie as they approached **the weathered one-seater ships that were apparently Beckett’s intended escape route from Savareen.**
>    Not that such things mattered anymore.
>
> <sub><sup>[Solo: A Star Wars Story - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ha, no sight of weathered one-seater ships in the movie, though.

Comment: @Essen - Indeed, nor any other communities further down the coast